# Reformatting date values when using them as URL parameters in a PowerQuery API request

Tags: excel, api, date, powerquery, m

I have two dates in my Excel table with the following format: "dd-mm-yyyy". These dates need to be sent as URL query parameters to an API endpoint for getting some data using PowerQuery. However, the API endpoint does not accept dates in that format. Therefore, I need to convert them to the format "mm-dd-yyyy" instead for it to work.

For getting the values from my table, I use the following code:

```
let GetNamedRange=(NamedRange) =>
 
let
    name = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=NamedRange]}[Content],
    value = name{0}[Column1]
in
    value
in
    GetNamedRange
```

This function, called "GetValue", is then called when inserting URL query parameters in my GET request:

```
Csv.Document(Web.Contents("my.api/leave/leavecsv", [Query = [periodStart = GetValue("periodStart"), periodEnd = GetValue("periodEnd"), department = GetValue("department")]]),[Delimiter=";", Columns=14, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])
```

Currently the cells for my dates are in Text format. I tried using Date.FromText(...) to format the dates, but I get an error saying the datetime format is invalid.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/date-fromtext

How can I propertly format my date values before inserting them as URL query parameters using PowerQuery?

Answer (score 3):

Ensure your dates are real dates and set to `type date`. then you can use the `Date.ToText` function:

```
let
    theDate = #date(2022,12,7),
    output = Date.ToText(theDate,"MM-dd-yyyy")
in
    output
```

If, for some reason, you must maintain your dates as text strings (I'd like to know why, if that's the case), you can convert them first to a "real" date, and then create the string:

```
let
    theDate = "13-12-2022",
    output = Date.ToText(Date.FromText(theDate, "en-150"),"MM-dd-yyyy")
in
    output
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you pass in a culture and format. i.e.

```
Date.FromText([Column1], [Format="dd-MM-yyyy", Culture="en-UK"])
```

Comment: When I try this, it says that I cannot convert a value of type record into type text. What parameter should I use for the text? Do I need to drill down in order to get the actual string value in the cell?

Comment: Where's your sample data?

Comment: In a locally stored Excel table.

Comment: You need to share a workbook as it isn't clear what you're doing. The code above works fine as I've tested it.